# Are all PAL-versions limited by the "PAL-bug" and were any measures taken to fix it?

Tags: digimon-world

When I first played Digimon World I really loved the game, but sadly the so caled "PAL-bug" rips out a big amount of the game.

For those who don't know it:

The PAL-bug causes that Agumon at the Mountain-castle won't start his dialouge.

So he also doesn't leave the passage he is guarding and you can't get further.
This is blocking a significant progress point of the game.
Making like 50% of the game inaccessable, because on the one hand to get further 1 or 2 special digimons have to be in the city which would be requiring to get some methods from the mountain castle or some items connected with those digimons. and even if you mannage to get ALL digimons into the city which aren't blocked by this bug you just have 1 more as needed for the end game area. but getting all of them by a great amount of support missed in the city is something I never managed to handle.

So are there any measures taken for PAL users of the game so they can also play the full game?
Where they able refund it since they couldn't play the game they paid for?
Where there some kind of patches send out (doubtful as we are talking about PSOne)?

Was this fixed for later versions and so there are multiple PAL-versions out with some working and some beeing more a demo as the full game?

Or was it just branded as "Bad luck for these PAL-users"?

If the latter is the case: is there anyway known to workaround this bug?

I have read stuff about just opening the disk case after a third sound so some parts of the map are loaded but actually not the digimons so I can walk through the passage.

But that doesn't help me either since I dont just want to visit the castle without interacting, but play the whole game...

Comment: Asking if Bandai has or will do something about a bug is off-topic. Try to focus on the issue itself, and ask how to get past it; that would be a good question, and something we can help with.

Comment: @Frank: Well since the game now is almost 20 years old, its quite certain they won't do anything anymore. my actual question is if they ever did. and thats on-topic, isn't it?

Comment: Eh...it's still straying into the developer territory a bit. I'd prefer if we just focused on how to get around it, without needing to mention Bandai at all. That should still help you, while keeping the question firmly in gaming territory.

Comment: @Frank: OK, As soon as I'm home I'll try to rephrase it that I'm mainly asking for a workaround. Whilest this workaround also can be part of an developers statement if there is one. Then that should be completely fine, am I right?

Comment: Don't ask for a developer statement. Do ask how to bypass or solve the issue.

Comment: @Frank I didn't ask for a developer statemant at all ;)

Comment: @Frank: I re-read it now to clarify the developer apsect I'm not asking for. and I really don't get how this is read as if I asked vor developer intentions. I asked: is there a patch, if so wher/how to get? if not was there a way to refund it? if not: are there known or anounced workarounds of the bug. No clue how this is interpreted as "off-toppic -> developers statement / intention".

Comment: Here's a **workaround**, if you're interested in playing the game until the end, but not necessarly on the PSX, you can download an emulator and pop your game in your computer. It's likely you're going to have to start over but at least you can use cheats in order to make agumon appear in the city. Unless that is, you own a gameshark or codebreaker, which then makes it possible to cheat in the PSX aswell